# Is it possible to flag messages in a chat room?

Tags: discussion, flags, chat

I was in a chat with one guy and it was going well but after some time the guy began using very bad language (vulgar language). I couldn't understand what I could do about it, so I quit chat. I felt very bad.

So how can I flag in chat room? Is there any option to flag in chat room for moderator attention?

Comment: Sure. When hovering over a chat message a flag icon will appear on the right before the star

Comment: What is *"verger language"*?

Comment: Vulgar perhaps? @jon

Comment: @Bart ah, possibly - given the meaning of *"verger"* I was surprised their language was considered synonymous with bad language!

Comment: Just bad language . i mean vulger

Comment: @Bart Where it is? i can't find.

Comment: See picture in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203346/248731

Comment: Obviously I don't know exactly what the situation is, but if the other user was swearing in general (i.e. not directed at you; *"this problem is pissing me off"*, for example) and it was making you feel uncomfortable, you can say that and ask them to tone it down, most people will. If they were being offensive towards you, flagging is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @Bart - That is not the right flag to use. Please don't advise people to use that one. It is only causes 10k chat users to review, and that is it.

Comment: So @Travis? I don't see there is a major issue just yet? We are the first line of defense.

Comment: @Bart - So? It is the wrong flag, it isn't just a "so what" scenario. There are no consequences and it usually only shows up to users who have no actions available aside from agreeing to remove the content. Chat on SO is a lot different than it is on the entire exchange. The basic flags almost never reach a moderator. That you don't see the issue is probably because you do not use the chat on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If it's a first offense I don't see why the users present can't handle it with the accompanying short suspension. If it keeps coming back sure, escalate it to a mod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to flag from chat. To do so, you need to select the drop down arrow on the left side of a message you are flagging:

[image: Chat Drop down]

From here, click `flag for moderator`:

[image: Flag for Moderator]

Fill out the input field explaining why you are flagging and then click OK.

[image: Why flag?]

---

The `flag as spam/offensive` option is also available. This flag will show to all users that have 10K+ reputation on the network.

Comment: Just for my own clarification, what is the actual difference between flag as offensive and flag for moderator? Does the flag as offensive not trigger a moderator review as well?

Comment: @Oldskool the flag for moderator goes directly for moderator attention... the spam/offensive notifies all 10k+ users which can then vote valid/invalid/not sure on the message... If enough users validate the flag, then it results in a 30 minute chat suspension for the user.