# What should I do about recruiter spam chat rooms without any messages?

Tags: support, chat, spam

I found [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/190999/) which has a recruitment spam title and no messages.

I know you're able to [flag *messages*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290555/) in a room as spam or for moderator attention, but what should I do when there aren't any messages in said room?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can:

1. post a message within the room, then mod flag your message explaining that the room's title/description is spammy, or
2. from the room owner's profile, go to the main profile and mod flag one of their posts, or
3. if the user has no posts (very unlikely), mod flag one of your own posts.

Comment: 4. Post on Meta

Comment: Should the account of the user who created this unwelcome advertising see some repercussions, too?

Comment: @tripleee A chat suspension, should one be meted out, wouldn't show up on the user's main profile page. Not sure if they even show up on the chat profile. But IMO this wouldn't warrant any publicly visible repercussion. Just freeze the room and let the user know that even chat rooms are not OK for spam/solicitation. BTW the search query linked on your profile is missing `is:a` to filter down to just answers.

Comment: Not everything that's unwanted is *unwelcoming*. Overuse and abuse of the term has basically become a meme at this point.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for clarifying - totally agree that a public flag is probably unnecessary here. Re the bug, nice catch; I only have a handful of questions and I'm guessing you didn't actually see one of them in the results :-)

Comment: @tripleee I didn't, until I swapped over to `is:q` to make sure I wasn't going crazy :-P

Comment: @ndugger "unwelcome" != "unwelcoming"

Comment: @TylerH Chat suspensions are shown on the chat profile page.